# Laravel 4 how to lazy load controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Recently I've discovered that Laravel 4 is including all the controllers on each request regardless if it needs it or not, even though Composer has the whole controller architecture mapped in its autoload. I'm trying to build a high traffic website and I'm trying to minimize the overhead as much as possible before starting to make any hardware scaling. Do you have any idea how can I "force" laravel 4 into lazy loading the classes, as in ... whenever they are requested by the code for the given request.

The way I see it now, when it parses the routes it includes all controllers, makes a reflection class of all of them to parse the methods so that it has them mapped in the request memory. IMO that's quite the overkill. A simple Hello World costs me 5Mb ram and 15ms page generation time. That is too much for me. It's like the most hyped framework at the moment and its hyped as lightweight but 5mb/15ms is not lightweight in any case :/

Answer (score -1):

There is a great argument/explanation here: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8175

Laravel 4 is meant to use more framework agnostic packages than Laravel 3.

Laravel 3 is very lightweight, perhaps you could look into using v3 instead. It's still actively being used and supported throughout the community.